# Enabling PortFowarding with Amper

Tags: router, wireless-router, routing, port-forwarding

Im trying to open ports on this router (Amper) its a fiber optics internet router and tv at the same time.

My problem is, I have set all these ports opens as you can see in this picture but none of them appear open on whatsmyip.org/portscanners.

The only thing that works is if I enable UPnP and let the game set my network config for me .

But I want to set it manually , how do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i found the solution.
When opening a port my router automatically fills the Internal Server Port but it does so incorrectly.
Therefore just changing to the correct internal SERVER port gets my port open.
(At least thats what i think im no expert lol)